# Не обрабатываются некоторые элементы в динамическом массиве

Tags: массивы, delphi

Весь мозг сломал уже. Укажите на ошибку.

```
i:=0;
while i<High(Shleif) do
Begin
 Shleif[i].integr:=Shleif[i].integr+1;
 If Shleif[i].integr>MAX_INTEGR then
  Begin
   Shleif[i]:=Shleif[High(Shleif)];
   SetLength(Shleif,High(Shleif));
  end else
  with Shleif[i] do
  Begin
   Действия над масивом, только чтение данных.
   i:=i+1;
  end;
end;
```

Так вот ошибка непонятная (для меня) - периодически некоторые элементы не обрабатываются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замени `while i<High(Shleif) do` на `while i<=High(Shleif) do`. В текущем виде не обрабатывается последний элемент массива.

Comment: огромное спасибо.... так лохануться.... просто жесть.......